# finding out which GUI is installed in linux

Tags: linux

Is there a command or way to figure out which GUI is installed on?
Or can you figure it out by looking at file structure, what's the best way

Comment: What do you mean by "which GUI is installed on"? What are you trying to find out exactly?

Comment: Agree with David. Do you mean "general GUI" = desktop environment like KDE or GNOME or GUI of particular application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type into terminal:

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
```